# What makes a recursive function finite

Tags: scala, recursion

I'm writing classes to represent a set of integers. This is how I've done it:

```
abstract class IntSet {
   def incl(x: Int): IntSet
   def union(x: IntSet): IntSet
   def union1(x: IntSet): IntSet
}

class Empty extends IntSet {
  def incl(x: Int) = new NonEmpty(x, new Empty, new Empty)
  def union(x: IntSet) = x
  def union1(x: IntSet) = x
}

class NonEmpty(var elem: Int, var left: IntSet, var right: IntSet)
extends IntSet {
   def incl(x: Int) = {
      if (x < elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left incl x, right)
      else if (x > elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right incl x)
      else this
   }
   def union(x: IntSet) = ((left union right) union x) incl elem
   def union1(x: IntSet) = ((left union1 x) union1 (right union1 x)) incl elem
}
```

Then I define two sets:

```
 val one = new NonEmpty(2, new Empty, new Empty).incl(5).incl(12)
 val two = new NonEmpty(1, new Empty, new Empty).incl(17).incl(12)
```

and try to invoke `union()` on them: 
Calling `one.union(two)` works good, but `one.union1(two)` results in StackOverflow exception. 

I know that recursive function must lead to non-recursively defined values to be finite. What are those values in the first case (union) and why can't the program reach those defined values in the second case (union1)?

The general question is more about math theory than Scala, but are there any tips (rules) to stick to when writting recursive functions in order to make them finite?

Comment: Your question is not clear and you haven't provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please, see also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Once you update your question with necessary details, you might get some reasonable answer.

Comment: @SergGr It looks like the question's been salvaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually want to decrease on one of your parameters to get down to a base
case. Your example is a bit complicated, but `union1` essentially has two
parameters: `x` and `this` (for our purposes, `this` can be considered a
"parameter"). Your base case is when `this` is `Empty`, so let's look at whether
you decrease on `this`.

Now, you make three recursive calls to `union1`. Let's look at the two simpler
ones: `left union1 x` and `right union1 x`. In these, you are definitely
decreasing on `this`. `left` and `right` must be smaller than `this` since they
do not include `elem`. So that's good, you will definitely reach the case where
`this` is `Empty`.

The third one, `(left union1 x) union1 (right union1 x)`, is a different story.
Since it also contains all of `x` on the left hand side, there will be no
decrease in `this` when `this == x`. For example, consider the case of taking the
union of a simple set with itself. Let `\/` denote `union1` and `+` denote
`incl`. Here is a basic idea of what your code computing `{1} \/ {1}` looks like:

```
{1} \/ {1}
(({} \/ {1}) \/ ({} \/ {1})) + 1
({1} \/ {1}) + 1
...
```

We now need to compute `{1} \/ {1}` again, so we will repeat this infinitely.

So, in general, make sure that at least one of the parameters you have a base
case for is decreasing. To be completely stack-overflow-free, you should also use
tail recursion with the [`@tailrec` annotation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/annotation/tailrec.html) to handle really large
sets, or find a way to use existing higher-order functions instead of recursion.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can see now that every example (input) would lead to x \/ x at some point.